# On the notation of the likelihood function

Tags: statistics, notation, conditional-probability, log-likelihood

Let $X$ be a random variable realized as the event $(X=x)$.
The corresponding **likelihood function** is given by

$$\mathcal{L}_x:\Theta\rightarrow[0,1]$$
$$\theta\mapsto P(X=x|\theta)$$

for a space $\Theta$ of parameter configurations $\theta$.

In the literature, $\mathcal{L}_x(\theta)$ is sometimes written as $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X=x)$. I assume this is done to emphasize that the event $(X=x)$ is 'given'.
However, this notation leads to confusion, since
it suggests that $\mathcal{L}_x$ is a probability density ('conditioning' on the event $X=x$), which appears to not be true in general (cf. second answer in [this thread on math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10971/why-isnt-likelihood-a-probability-density-function)).

So my questions are:

1. Is $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X=x)$ just 'overloading' the notation $f(\cdot|\cdot)$, or is there some hidden meaning/analogy to conditional probability $P(\cdot|\cdot)$ which I am missing?
2. Are there other areas in mathematics where $f(\cdot|\cdot)$ is used? Could you provide an example?

Currently, I think $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X=x)$ is a bad notational choice because it caused confusion for me when trying to understand the likelihood function.
Especially since at any point $\theta$, one has $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X=x)=P(X=x|\theta)$

Comment: In statistics is is common practice to list parameters and other relevant information to the right of a $|$ symbol. The $|$ symbol is not reserved for conditional probability. Some authors use $;$ instead of $|.$

Comment: For any $\theta$, one has $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X=x)=P(X=x|\theta)$. I find this very confusing. Especially in bayesian inference, one often encounters the expression $P(A|B)$ which is called 'likelihood'. Am I just to assume that this is what I called $\mathcal{L}(B|A)$? Also, I've read both 'prior likelihood' and 'posterior likelihood', but also 'prior probability' and 'posterior probability'. This is all very confusing to me and I don't really understand why one would make this distinction in the first place.

Comment: The point of the first form is that the likelihood function is viewed as a function of the parameter $\theta$ once data $x$ is observed. The constant that makes the PDF integrate (or sum) to unity is often omitted. (If you are maximizing the likelihood function to find $\theta$ that maximizes it, then that constant is not relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

In classical (frequentist) statistics $\theta$ is unknown *constant*, thus there is no sense in viewing $L(\theta|X)$ in any probabilistic manner. As you can see in the linked thread, $L(\theta|X)$ does not even need to be integrated (w.r.t. $\theta$) to one. Hence, the more common notation is $L(\theta; X=x)$ or its shorthand $L(\theta; X)$ or $L(\theta; x)$, which just designates the fact that we view it as a function of $\theta$ over the parametric space $\Theta$, and regard the $X$ as constant $X=x$.

In the case you are Bayesian, then you usually denote the posterior distribution of $\theta$ by $f(\theta|...)$ or $p(\theta|...)$, not to confuse it with the classical likelihood function. But to this notation to make sense you *must* assume a prior distribution for $\theta$, $f(\theta)$. That is, from the very beginning you regard $\theta$ as a random variable and not as a constant.

Comment: (+1) for showing the Bayesian point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Consider data $x = 8$ sampled from a binomial population with success parameter $\theta$ (unknown and to be estimated) and a known number of Bernoulli trials $n = 12.$

**PDF.** If it happens that $\theta = 0.5,$ then the PDF gives
you the probability of getting $X = 8:$
$$f(x |n=12, \theta=0.5) = {n \choose x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}\\ = {12 \choose x}.5^x(1-.5)^{12-x} = {12\choose x}(.5)^{12},$$ for $x = 0, 1, \dots, 12.$

```
plot(0:12, dbinom(0:12, 12, 1/2), type="h", 
     lwd=2, col="blue", ylab="PDF", xlab="x", 
     main="PDF of BINOM(12, 1/2)")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]

**Likelihood.** Now, if you have observed $x = 8$ and wish to find
the corresponding estimate $\hat \theta$ of $\theta,$
then the PDF, considered now as a *likelihood* function,
might be written as

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta|x,n) = \mathcal{L}(\theta|8,12)\propto \theta^x(1=\theta)^{n-x} = \theta^8(1-\theta)^4,$$
for $0 < \theta < 1,$
where the symbol $\propto$ (read 'proportional to') is
used as a reminder that the (now irrelevant) constant
${n\choose x}$ has been omitted.
Maximixing $\mathcal{L}(\theta|8,12)$ in $\theta$ we obtain the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) $\hat\theta = x/n = 9/12 = 2/3.$

```
th = seq(0, 1, by=.01)
like = dbinom(8, 12, th)
plot(th, like, type= "l", ylab="Likelihood", 
     xlab = "theta", lwd=2, 
     main="Likelihood Function")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=8/12, col="maroon")

mle = th[like==max(like)];  mle
[1] 0.67
```

[image]

**Comparison.** It is simple to say that the PDF and the likelihood
function are the 'same thing'. But not exactly true.

- The PDF is a function of $x,$ for given
  parameters $n$ and $\theta.$ As in the first plot above.
- The likelihood function is a function of
  unknown $\theta$ for known values $n = 12, x = 8.$
  As in the second plot.

It not not surprising that
this difference in viewpoint gets shown explicitly in the notation.

Comment: I see. I think my confusion stems from seeing the term likelihood used in Bayes' formula $P(H|E)=\frac{P(H)}{P(E)}P(E|H)$. By itself, $P(E|H)=\mathcal{L}(H|E)$ is just a value, and from the above I deduce that its interpretation as probability/likelihood depends on what is assumed to vary. I always assumed that in Bayesian inference one has a *fixed* initial hypothesis $H$, whose probability of being true is 'updated' given some new evidence $E$. However, I don't see how $H$ varies. If you could answer how it does, this would be of great help. I will re-read the Wikipedia article for now.